# Mysterious javascript behaviour: unequal equals

Tags: javascript

I really don't know how is it possible, and I couldn't reproduce the error in a simplified environment, say JSFiddle. But here is how it looks in my application.

I'm trying to convert value that can be 'True', 'False' or 'something else' string into boolean if it is either True or False. In most cases it works just fine (although they may be a slicker way of doing the conversion) as it is shown on the picture below

[image]

however on occasion it fails and the value of the watch shows as follow:

[image]

So suddenly string variable with a value of "True" is not equal to a "True" string literal. I'm lost. How is it possible? What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your strings contain characters that your debugging tools don't show. Here's an example in Google Chrome's Console:

```
> var a = "foo";
> var b = "foo\r";
> a
"foo"
> b
"foo"
> a === b
false
```

It is really difficult to say what's going on in your case but you could work with the `.length` and `.charAt(i)` properties of the 'mysterious' strings to find out what's going on.

Comment: yes, just got to it myself and was trying to post an answer (which is somethin I cannot do within 8 hours it appears)

Ok, Got it! Posting your questions to stackoverflow is helpful on its own. 

I did check `value.length` and was slightly surprised to see `5`
it was a `\0` left after deserializing the data from server.

Comment: A simple `console.log(value.split(""));` might help work out whats going on.

Comment: I guessed it must be it when I realised the problem is with the last one of the strings in array coming from server. As I said sometimes just posting here helps. Marked it as answer as the guess in the right direction. thanks all for social coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just for sanity, test for `=== "True"`, using double quotes rather than single. It **shouldn't** matter, but just rule it out :)

Comment: did that before posting but felt really silly doing it, thought I'm going mad and it's about time to ask the question here. Obviously the results were, as expected, unexpected and wrong. But at least consistent.

Comment: @Joe the logic is correct, he will either have a boolean true or false   or the value as a string